# How can I defer a message in SLICC

Tags: gem5

I am new to gem5 and SLICC. Currently, I am gonna try to defer some messages and send them later. However, I do not know how I can store them temporarily. For example enqueue them first and then pop them in proper occasions?

Comment: Also ask on mailing list.

Comment: thanks. I have sent email to gem5 user.